# How to create environments with multiple channels in conda

Tags: python-3.x, windows, conda, environment, channel

I would like to know how to create environments that includes packages from various channels, such as the default python channel and the conda-forge channel.

I know I can install packages after the creation of the environment. But it is recommended to install all the programs we want in this environment at the same time, to prevent dependency conflicts ([link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)).

Do I have to focus on the default channel at the creation, then to install packages from the other channels? Or is there a better way to prepare my environments?

PS: I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

Repeating the `-c` or `--channel` argument allows you to specify multiple different channels. Ordering is not important.

`conda create -n MyAwesomeEnv PackageA PackageB PackageC -c ChannelAlpha -c ChannelBeta`

Comment: `package -c conda-forge -c anaconda` which channel would be chosen if both channels have the package?